# Форма приветствия: "Доброго времени суток"

Tags: стилистика

Последнее время стала распространенной такая форма приветствия: **доброго времени суток**. Меня она несколько коробит. Хотелось бы узнать ваше мнение. Спасибо.

Comment: здравствуйте!!!
это и приветствие сейчас читающим и в общем.
доброго времени суток-это жжжжжжесть!!!!!!!!!!!!
не надо мудрствовать и что-то придумывать))))))))))))))))
все придумано!!!!!!!!
ЗДРАВСТВУЙТЕ!!!
и днем и ночью!!!и приветствие!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Очень интересно, но получается, что приветствия выглядят так: "Добрый день!", "Добрый вечер!", "Доброе утро!". Т. е. все в именительном падеже. А вот "Доброй ночи!" — это уже получается прощание. Родительный падеж. Вот и осмысленность фразы "доброго времени суток" какая-то неясная. Вроде бы это и не прощание, и не приветствие. Да и громоздко. Поэтому нужно этой фразы избегать и употреблять более общеупотребительные и стандартные аналоги.

Comment: Кстати, "доброй ночи" стали употреблять как приветствие.  Хотя наряду с "покойной ночи" это было принято при прощании на ночь. Причём пришло это с ночных эфиров радио и ТВ.

Comment: Приветствия в именительном падеже звучат нейтрально. А "доброй ночи" и "доброго времени суток" можно воспринимать как пожелание. Думаю, таким образом адресант хочет высказать свою доброжелательность (а в случае с временем суток это может показаться несколько заискивающе, потому, вероятно, многим и не нравится такая формулировка, как, впрочем, и мне).

Answer (score 8):

На мой взгляд, это явно косноязычная и тяжеловесная конструкция, и никакого юмора я здесь не нахожу!
Есть веками проверенное и всем понятное слово "Здравствуйте!", вот с него-то и можно начинать общение.

Answer (score 4):

Мне тоже не нравится этот оборот, и я его никогда не использую. Приветствия "добрый день и т.д." предпочтительны при устном общении. В письменной речи лучше использовать общеупотребительные "здравствуйте", "приветствую Вас". Вообще, обороты "добрый день и т.д.", по правилам этикета, используются при обращении к хорошо знакомым, близким людям. В крайнем случае можно употребить оборот с "добрый", обозначив то время суток, в момент которого вы пишете данное письмо. Неважно, что Ваш адресат будет читать эти слова в другое время суток.

Comment: Мне кажется, эта фраза пришла с распространением сети Интернет ,когда одновременно общаются люди из разных часовых поясов. Ведь при общении в форуме или чате я могу точно знать, что у меня день, а у собеседника ночь.Если на бумаге письмо, еще неизвестно, когда его прочитают, а здесь ясно: сейчас! И что использовать? Хотя такой вариант и мне не нравится.

Answer (score 4):

Проще сказать "здравствуйте" вместо "доброго времени суток". :)

Answer (score 3):

Ну вот, какие все строгие. А по-моему, "доброго времени суток" - просто юмор, оживление затертого оборота. И конечно, это выражение можно использовать только в интернете и в том случае, когда общение идет на неформальном уровне. То есть его используют те, кто не собирается спрашивать на это разрешение (и молодцы, кстати).

Здесь бы я не стала его употреблять: обстановка слишком академическая...

Comment: Я этот "юмор" слышу или читаю раз пятьдесят на дню.
После которого повторения юмор становится пошлостью?

Comment: Знаете, недавно был такой случай. Мы с сыном были в кафе, а он у меня ребенок не тихий. И вот, один из посетителей сделал нам (очень интеллигентно) замечание.  
И знаете, я не расстроилась, но мне стало __жалко__ этого человека. Ведь он такой незащищенный, на него действует неподобающее поведение окружающих. Я бы на его месте вообще не среагировала: ну шумят - и ладно, я о своем буду думать.  

Мне кажется, что с Вами тоже творится что-то такое, Вы очень резко реагируете на "несовершенство мира". Не надо! Неудобные люди вокруг нас были и будут, не давайте им (нам) испортить Ваше настроение!

Comment: Я только сейчас увидел этот коммент... Собственно, отчечать спустя полгода - не лучшая идея, но все ж...

Я *не* отрицаю наличие у меня жизненных проблем , в чем-то, кстати, сходных с теми, о которых Вы упоминали в личке.   
Я *не* отрицаю повышенное ощущение несовершенства мира.  
Я отрицаю, что оба этих фактора сказались на моей психике или чём-то еще настолько, что это бросается в глаза окружающим. Мне бы как раз *научится* делать замечания в подобных ситуациях... Я агрессивен только применительно к спорам об абстактных материях.

Comment: Да, полгода большой срок... я как-то позабыла наши споры. Все в прошлом...

Comment: Ну и слава Богу.  
С праздником!
Весны в душе и в семье.

Answer (score 3):

Если в двух словах, то мне очень не нравится за косноязычие.
Когда не знаешь, какое время у собеседника, говори "Добрый день!" - не ошибёшься. День это еще и вполне употребимый синоним суткам.

Answer (score 2):

Я ничего плохого в этом приветствии не вижу, хотя лично его не употребляю. Когда телеведущий из московской телестудии говорит "Доброе утро!", как должны воспринимать это телезрители из Владивостока, которые уже садятся ужинать?

Меня немного смущает, когда слышу другую новую форму приветствия - "Добрый!". Сначала казалось, что люди слова проглатывают, но потом вслушалась - действительно просто "добрый", без уточнения времени суток.

Comment: Это наверное в ответ говорят?

-- Добрый день!

-- Добрый!

Такое слышал. А чтобы в качестве 1-ой фразы приветствия, то пока не приходилось встречаться.

Comment: Да, в качестве первого приветствия. Или вообще в ответ на "Здравствуйте".

Comment: Просто "добрый" ни разу пока не слышала. Но  вполне в духе современных тенденций. По тому же телевизору постоянно "чел" вместо "человек" (хотя сейчас не знаю, телевизор давно не смотрю).

Comment: Не слышал такого. Но вот у голландцев (видимо, не только) есть манера проглатывать слово "добрый". Говорят на английском просто "морнинг".
На голландском - тоже, но голландская фонетика непривычному русскому уху - это нечто. "Goeten Morgen" читается примерно как "Хуэнморха". Поэтому когда говорят просто "Морда" - это на слух даже приятнее.

Answer (score 1):

Как я заметил, данное приветствие набирает популярность в интернете с недавних пор. Используется оно в соцсетях и форумах в связи с тем, что люди общаются в разных часовых поясах и не могут знать, как поприветствовать своих собеседников: *добрый вечер*, *добрый день* или *доброе утро*. Поэтому фраза *доброго времени суток* и подразумевает в себе что-то одно из *доброго*.

Answer (score 1):

(1) На мой взгляд, милые нашему уху "доброе утро, "добрый вечер" и "добрый день" отличаются от более нейтрального "здравствуйте" тем, что желая быть более приятным и менее формальным, собеседник потрудился упомянуть в своем приветствии конкретное время суток. Если же, не зная, какое у вас время суток, он говорит или пишет о "добром времени суток" вообще, то это уже выглядит как пародия. Представьте, что не зная имени собеседника, вы ради приятности поприветствуете его так: "Здравствуйте, обладатель имени".

(2) С другой стороны,  приветствия "доброе утро, "добрый вечер" и "добрый день" выражены в именительном падеже и, если вдуматься, это восклицания и призыв к сопереживанию, совместной радости по поводу того, что выдалось доброе утро (день, вечер). Опять же, все это становится бессмысленным, если вас с собеседником разделяют многое часовые пояса или написание и чтение текста происходят не одновременно.

(3) И наконец, "доброго времени суток" написано в родительном падеже, который в русском языке означает пожелание, традиционно используемое именно как прощание, а не как приветствие. Но если даже заменить его на "доброе время суток", в силе остаются п. 1 и 2.

А вот мнение известого лингвиста д. ф. н., проф. М. А. Кронгауза, приведенное на сайте [Грамота.ру](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=%20256612):

> Употребление приветствий регулируется не столько правилами (о правилах
>   уместно говорить, когда речь идет о правописании), сколько нормами
>   речевого этикета.
>
> Вот что пишет о приветствии Доброй ночи! известный российский лингвист
>   д. ф. н., проф. М. А. Кронгауз в книге «Русский язык на грани нервного
>   срыва» (М., 2008):  Среди новых «уродцев» речевого этикета есть и
>   исконно русские. Одно из самых нелюбимых мной – новое и уже вполне
>   прижившееся приветствие «Доброй ночи!». Оно появилось вместе с новым
>   явлением – прямым ночным эфиром. Сначала в речи ведущих, которые таким
>   образом – с особым шиком – здоровались со зрителями/слушателями,
>   звонившими ночью в студию. Потом же «Доброй ночи!» было подхвачено и
>   самими звонившими и даже вышло за пределы студийных бесед. Например,
>   оно иногда используется как приветствие при телефонном звонке в
>   слишком позднее время.
>
> В действительности, появление такого приветствия противоречит многим
>   нормам языка. Во-первых, в европейских языках аналогичная формула
>   (good night, Gute Nacht и bonne nuit) используется именно при
>   прощании, в отличие от дневного приветствия типа английских good
>   morning, good evening, немецких Guten Morgen, Guten Tag, Guten Abend
>   или французских bonjour, bonsoir. Это соответствует и обычному
>   русскому прощанию «Спокойной ночи!». Во-вторых, в русском языке
>   «Доброй ночи!» как формула прощания уже существует, хотя и
>   используется значительно реже, чем «Спокойной ночи!». В-третьих, в ней
>   представлен родительный падеж, который в русском языке означает
>   пожелание, традиционно используемое именно как прощание: «Счастливого
>   пути!», «Удачи!», «Счастья вам!» и т. д. (с опущенным глаголом
>   «желаю»). Приветствие же выражается другим падежом («Добрый день!»,
>   «Хлеб да соль»!).
>
> В последнее время по аналогии с этим появляются и новые «неправильные»
>   приветствия. Например, в Интернете все чаще встречается **«Доброго
>   времени суток!»,** подчеркивающее тот факт, что электронное письмо
>   может быть получено в любое время.
>
> Как лингвист, я бы всячески рекомендовал не расшатывать стройную
>   систему русского этикета и не использовать приветствий в родительном
>   падеже. В том же Интернете встречается и более грамотное приветствие
>   «Доброе время суток!». Игра сохраняется, а правила соблюдены. Но при
>   всем при этом я рискую оказаться в положении авторов, боровшихся с
>   прощанием «Пока!». Ведь последнюю точку ставит не лингвист, а народ. И
>   если слово овладевает массами, а массы – словом, то никакой лингвист
>   не сможет его запретить. Так что поживем – увидим.

Answer (score 0):

Тю, фразу "доброе время" суток можно употребить в письме и *не ошибиться с временем* суток, поэтому и такая распространенная стала. "Здравствуйте" — уж очень затертое и, как по мне, не очень красивое слово, состоящее почти из одних согласных. Я вообще использую: "Доброе время суток!". По аналогии с "Добрый день", "Добрый вечер" и т.д.

Говорили о том, что по правилам этикета нельзя сказать незнакомому человеку "добрый день". Где такое написано, покажите мне. Нельзя сказать: "Привет". Почитать можно тут, например: http://www.wild-mistress.ru/wm/wm.nsf/publicall/2007-08-23-596523.html .

*Вот и осмысленность фразы "доброго времени суток" какая-то неясная. Вроде бы это и не прощание, и не приветствие.*
Что тут неясного? Чем это приветствие хуже, чем "Добрый день"? Правда, как я уже писал, "доброе время суток" звучит правильнее, по-моему.

Answer (score 0):

Не читал всех комментариев, может ответ кто-то и внес. Как правило, "доброе время суток" адресуется тогда, когда мы не знаем, какое время суток у адресата. В письменной форме, электронной, - письмо отправленное в другую страну. Мы не знаем, когда оно будет прочитано, вот от этого и такое обращение. Если вопрос задан применительно к повседневной жизни, то это выглядит весьма глупым, некорректно, если так обращаться вживую. Это не для этого случая фраза.

Answer (score 0):

Звучит нелепо. Как будто «доброго дня недели» или «доброго времени года». А вообще, традиционное «Добрый день!» совершенно правильно. Ведь и папуас, и ирокез начинают трудовой день с проверки почты. А добрым вечером отходят ко сну, с горячей скво уже и не до почты...

Answer (score 0):

Эту фразу, на мой взгляд, удобно использовать не в живом общении, а в письмах. Например, когда ты хочешь начать общаться с человеком в интернете ты пишешь "Доброго времени суток" (использовать привет не всегда уместно, так как может быть принято за дерзость, а Здравствуйте может быть принято слишком официально), потому что не знаешь в какое время прочтет письмо твой собеседник (к тому же, он может оказаться из другого часового пояса). Та же система и с бумажными письмами